# Adverb or Relative clause

Tags: adverbs

Is "by the time"a subordinate conjunction used to introduce Adverb time clause as mentioned  at few sites. 
Ex-I reached there by the time he started. 
I feel the clause following "time"has "when/that"implied and does the work of a relative clause modifying the Noun "time".

Answer (score 0):

> I reached there by [the {time he started}].

The relative clause *he started* integrates with the noun *time* to form the nominal *time he started*, which then is determined by *the* to form the definite noun phrase.

Note that *he started* is a relative clause in that it lacks the information as to when he started.

If he started at 11 o'clock, the sentence means:

> I reached there by 11 o'clock.

Comment: Thanks JK2.How do you interpret 'with the aim that' 'due to the fact that etc which are taken as compound subordinating conjunction  to introduce adverb clause? Though it can introduce adverb clause one argument can be that the 'that clause'(acting as Noun clause) can be seen to be in apposition to Noun"aim/fact". ExampleHe did this with the aim that nobody should blame him/due to the fact that he was not happy. Seek Your interpretation please. Thanks